# Why would scanf crash while reading a string?

Tags: c, string, scanf

This is just a small program I wrote to find a problem with a larger one. Everything changes when I add the line with scanf. I know it is not safe, I read other threads concerning printf errors that suggest other functions. Anything but cin is fine. Btw, I didn't choose the type definitions of the 'messages', that came from my teachers, so I cannot change them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char message1 [] = "amfdalkfaklmdklfamd.";
char message2 [] = "fnmakajkkjlkjs.";
char initializer [] = ".";
char* com;
char* word;
int main()
{   
    com = initializer;
    int i = 1;
    while (i !=4)
    {   
        printf ("%s \n", com);
        scanf("%s",word);
        i++;
    };  
    return 0;
}
```

The problem: after a single iteration the program exits, nothing is printed.

Comment: You need a buffer into which scanf can put the data from the keyboard.

Comment: The answer was evident just from reading the title.

Answer (score 6):

The reason the `scanf` will crash is buffer is not initialized: `word` has not been assigned a value, so it is pointing nowhere.

You can fix it by allocating some memory to your buffer, and limiting `scanf` to a certain number of characters, like this:

```
char word[20];
...
scanf("%19s", word);
```

Note that the number between `%` and `s`, which signifies the maximum number of characters in a string, is less by `1` than the length of the actual buffer. This is because of null terminator, which is required for C strings.

Comment: Isn't there a way to correct my program without asking for a fixed amount of space in compilation time?

Comment: @galactus You can ask for a fixed amount of space at runtime, using `malloc` and friends. But you cannot fix it if you want to use `scanf` unless you allocate (in some way) a fixed amount of space.

Comment: If it is not cin, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

`com` is a pointer whose value is the address of the literal string `initializer`. Literal strings are contained within read-only memory areas, but the `scanf` function will attempt to **write** into the address given to it, this is an access-violation and causes the OS to kill your process, hence the crash you're seeing.

Change your `scanf` code to resemble this, note the addition of width limit in the `%s` placeholder, as well as the use of the `scanf_s` version to ensure there is no buffer overflow.

```
static int const BufferLength = 2048; // 2KiB should be sufficient
char* buffer = calloc( BufferLength , 1 ); 
if( buffer == null ) exit(1);
int fieldCount = scanf_s("%2047s", buffer, BufferLength );
if( fieldCount == 1 ) {
    // do stuff with `buffer`
}
free( buffer );
```

Note that `calloc` zeroes memory before returning, which means that `buffer` can serve as a null-terminated string directly, whereas a string allocated with `malloc` cannot (unless you zero it yourself).

Comment: But I need to initialize it somehow.. or not? What about the iterations? Would it crash if it got to scanf a second time?

Comment: I think that "DO NOT USE SCANF EVER" is too strict an advise. It can definitely be used safely (unlike, say, `gets`, which is hopeless). One needs to be careful with it, but that is true about C programming in general.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Sorry, I was getting confused between `gets` and `scanf`. I'm revising my answer now.

Comment: `scanf("%2047s", buffer, BufferLength);` is a blunder, ITYM `scanf("%2047s", buffer);`

Comment: com has nothing to do with the scanf call, and the crash has nothing to do with writing into a literal string. And you're passing two many arguments to scanf. And there's no need to clear the buffer before reading into it. And there ought to be a check for calloc failing.

Answer (score 0):

`word` has no memory associated with it.

```
char* word;
scanf("%s",word);
```

Could use

```
char word[100];
word[0] = '\0';
scanf("%99s",word);
```

---

If available, use `getline()`.

Although not standard C, `getline()` will dynamicaly allocate memory for arbitrarily long user input.

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
  printf("%s", line);
}
free(line);
```

[Linux Programmer's Manual GETLINE(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)